# count in IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the following IF statement in a loop, and if a counter increases by 1 if the statement is true.

The problem is that even when the statement is not true, the counter is increased by one anyways.

```
For i = 2 To lRow
If (ptfile.Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 17).Value - ptfile.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 17).Value) < 1440 Or (ptfile.Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 17).Value - ptfile.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 17).Value) > 1440 Then
cnt = cnt + 1
casenames2.Worksheets(1).Cells(cnt, 2).Value = ptnames
casenames2.Worksheets(1).Cells(cnt, 3).Value = i
End If

Next i
```

Error is runtime error 6, overflow.
Please help,

Comment: In which line of code throws the error ?

Comment: How are `i` and `cnt` declared? What is the value of `lRow` when you get overflows? When you say "counter", are you referring to the ***loop counter*** `i`, or your variable `cnt`?

Comment: I was referring to the loop counter. The error was in the if statement as in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying your IF statement it says

```
If (something) < 1440 Or (something) > 1440 Then
    cnt = cnt + 1
```

So the only case where the condition is FALSE and the counter is not increased is when (something) equals 1440 exactly.